# is there any managed mongo DB service that AWS provide?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am looking to use mongo DB for my project but dont want to go in administrative overhead to manage mongo services.

As my project is currently hosting most of its component on AWS, i am looking for a managed mongo DB service (if any) provided by AWS.

AWS provides Dynamo DB as managed service and its well documented but accesing Mongo DB managed service over AWS is not very clear to me.

I have read about Mongo DB managed service - 'Atlas' but not sure can i access it as a service in my existing AWS instances.

Please provide your inputs for the best practice suitable for this scenario.

Comment: FWIW, AWS launched a managed "MongoDB compatible" service this month called [Amazon DocumentDB](https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/).  I think MongoDB Atlas is a better option for most people, at least for side projects. [I'm only posting this as a comment because I can't post an answer to a closed question.]

Comment: this is quite a valid Q. Closing this is just unfair. There is no separate SE site for mongodb or aws. So this Q belongs to here. AWS is part of developers and IT people today. And so to know and Question about the services offered by AWS is obvious. Some on should reopen this Q.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There is no Managed MongoDB Service provided by AWS.**

However, there are managed MongoDB services which provides hosting on AWS (in addition to Azure, GCP etc. MongoDB Atlas is an example.

MongoDB Atlas provides managed mongoDB service with options to host on AWS and you may opt to use that. You can choose the region of your preference and then use VPC Peering feature to make the application servers in your existing VPC/Account communicate with the MongoDB Atlas Setup.

You can read more about all these at https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas